# A combinations problem.

Tags: combinations

Given a number $N$ and $M$, how to find the possible combinations for

```
 a+b+... = N where a,b... <= M.
```

Ex:

```
N = 3 and M = 3
```

So the combinations would be

```
(3,[1+1+1],[1+2],[2+1]) which is 4.
```

Comment: I think that this problem (when different number orders are considered identical) has been solved only very recently (a few years ago at most).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** let $r=\min\{M,N\}$.You need to find all possible combination from the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, r\}$ that sum up to $N$.
You have three cases (two cases in fact but I separate the 1st and the 2nd):

- $N=M$: the combination is $2^{N-1}$. Because you are looking for a combination in the set $\{1, \cdots, N\}$ that sum up to $N$.
- $N=\min\{M,N\}$: the combination is $2^{N-1}$. Same reason as first bullet.
- $M=\min\{M,N\}$: the combination is $2^{M}-1$. Here you are looking for a combination in the set $\{1, \cdots, M\}$ that sum up to $N$. You have to be careful here because I think you have to study the difference $N-M$. At the first time, I supposed that $N-M=1$ to get $2^M-1$ but the more general formula in this case I think is: $2^M-2+\sum_{i=1}^{N-M}i=2^M-2+\dfrac{(N-M)(N-M+1)}{2}$.

If I did understand the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: if N = M ? for the case in the above given example ?

Comment: In that case, it is $2^{N-1}$. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to count $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ as being distinct? If not, then the number of combinations is just the coefficient of $x^N$ in $\prod_{k = 1}^M \frac{1}{1-x^k}$.

Comment: yes i want 1,2 and 2,1 as distinct pairs.

Answer (score 1):

A *partition* of a positive integer $n$, is a way of writing $n$ as a sum of positive integers.

Two sums that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition.

If the order **does** matter, then each sum becomes a *composition*.

For example, $4$ can be partitioned in five distinct ways:

```
4
3 + 1
2 + 2
2 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

And it can be composed in eight distinct ways:

```
4
3 + 1
1 + 3
2 + 2
2 + 1 + 1
1 + 2 + 1
1 + 1 + 2
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

---

Function $p(n)$ represents the number of possible partitions of a natural number $n$:

- The generating function for $p(n)$ is given by $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^n = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac {1}{1-x^k} \right)$
- An asymptotic expression for $p(n)$ is given by $\displaystyle p(n) \sim \frac {1} {4n\sqrt3} \exp\left({\pi \sqrt {\frac{2n}{3}}}\right)$

Function $c(n)$ represents the number of possible compositions of a natural number $n$:

- It is given by $\displaystyle c(n) = 2^{n-1}$

---

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) for more information on partitions.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) for more information on compositions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_a = S_b = S_c = ... = S_N = 1+x+x^2+...+x^M$. Now consider the product $P=S_aS_bS_c...S_N$. In this product the coefficient of $x^N$ is what we require.

$$
P = \left(\sum _{i=0}^M x^i\right)^N = \left(\frac{1-x^{M+1}}{1-x}\right)^N$$